# Devise: Routes messed up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have just installed devise, but the default routes & views they gave me are all screwed up. I am getting a ton of errors trying to access the views. I am using rails 3.2.13 & the newest devise (1.1.rc0)

Here are some errors I am getting with the following generated User model (using `rails generate devise User`)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :activatable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end
```

After running migrations, this was added in my routes file

```
devise_for :users
```

**When I try accessing the sign_up page I get this error**

```
undefined method `user_registration_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f8079d87c68>:0x007f8079badc30>
```

Here is the view where the error occurs

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource_name, resource, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p><%= f.label :email %></p>
  <p><%= f.text_field :email %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :password %></p>
  <p><%= f.password_field :password %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :password_confirmation %></p>
  <p><%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></p>

  <p><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></p>
<% end %>

<%= render :partial => "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Pretty obvious why this fails because here is the return of my rake routes

```
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)              devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)              devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)             devise/sessions#destroy
            password POST   /users/password(.:format)             devise/passwords#create {:name_prefix=>:user}
        new_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)         devise/passwords#new {:name_prefix=>:user}
       edit_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)        devise/passwords#edit {:name_prefix=>:user}
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)             devise/passwords#update {:name_prefix=>:user}
                     POST   /users/registration(.:format)         devise/registrations#create {:name_prefix=>"user_registration"}
                 new GET    /users/registration/sign_up(.:format) devise/registrations#new {:name_prefix=>"user_registration"}
                edit GET    /users/registration/edit(.:format)    devise/registrations#edit {:name_prefix=>"user_registration"}
                     PUT    /users/registration(.:format)         devise/registrations#update {:name_prefix=>"user_registration"}
                     DELETE /users/registration(.:format)         devise/registrations#destroy {:name_prefix=>"user_registration"}
        confirmation POST   /users/confirmation(.:format)         devise/confirmations#create {:name_prefix=>:user}
    new_confirmation GET    /users/confirmation/new(.:format)     devise/confirmations#new {:name_prefix=>:user}
                     GET    /users/confirmation(.:format)         devise/confirmations#show {:name_prefix=>:user}
```

Clearly the correct route is `new_path`.

Here is another error I am getting trying to access the sign_in view

```
wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
```

View

```
<h2>Sign in</h2>

<%= form_for(resource_name, resource, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <p><%= f.label :email %></p>
  <p><%= f.text_field :email %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :password %></p>
  <p><%= f.password_field :password %></p>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <p><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></p>
  <% end -%>

  <p><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></p>
<% end %>

<%= render :partial => "devise/shared/links" %>
```

I have used devise before, but I don't remember getting all of these errors. What is going on? I didn't think it was broken out of the box.

Comment: Can you share how you have defined the routes in routes.rb file.

Comment: Of course, Ill make that edit now

Comment: Which version of devise have you installed? You say latest and then mention `1.1.rc0`. Latest version of devise is `3.2.4`

Comment: All I did to install devise was add `gem 'devise'` to my gemfile. Then it did this when I ran `bundle install` `Installing devise (1.1.rc0)`

Comment: Let us discuss this on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the `wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)` error, update the `form_for` in view as

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

Routes should be defined as below in `routes.rb`:

```
devise_for :users
```

There is some problem with the `devise` version. I would suggest you to update the `Gemfile` with specific version of Devise as shown below:

```
gem 'devise', '~> 3.2.4'      ## instead of gem 'devise'
```

and run `bundle install`.